# What should be the (p,d,q) and (P,D,Q) for SARIMAX

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I'm working on time series data using SARIMA. So far I made the data stationary, I plotted ACF, PACF of the stationary data. But i'm unable to guage the parameters from the ACF, PACF plots.

Could someone let me know how to look at the plot. Thanks

Below is the plot
[image: ACF PACF]

Comment: Are you using statsmodels? I ask because the definition of (P,D,Q) is often implementation specific - i.e. for statsmodels its actually (P,D,Q,s) and in your case I'd tend to start with (P,D,Q,s)=(1,0,0,7) and (p,d,q)=(1,0,0) or perhaps (2,0,0) and see how you go.

Comment: I apologise. Yes it's (P,D,Q.s) . 
1. Am correct to assume that the value of 'p' is the no.of  first positive ticks inPACF above confidence interval and should ignore the negative ticks?

2. Shouldn't D =1 as there should be one seasonal difference needed? at 7

Comment: Yes my guess is you have daily data with a weekly "seasonal" effect (i.e. hence s=7). The large positive spikes on the ACF support this. Then you can try increasing p (i.e. 1,2 or 3) and seeing what the ACF / PACF of the final residuals look like.

Comment: Daily data is often driven by FIXED i.e repetitive DAILY EFFECTS and possibly some arima memory. The arima portion should be identified on the data CONDITIONED FOR latent deterministic effects possibly level shifts , local time trends, holiday effects and perhaps some candidate causals like price or advertising. If you post your data I will try and help further.